# How to make instances of a class unique each time in a loop

Tags: c#, class

I need help with a console application I'm making. I'm making a application to use for studying. I want to be able to start it up, enter how many questions I want to have, enter question and answer for each question, use a looping method that will forever loop and ask those same questions over and over. Thought this would be really useful. But I have meet a problem on the way. I use a class to create instances for the questions and their respective answers, but I don't know how to make the instance name different for each question. Here's the code below

```
namespace glosor
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, please enter how many questions you would like to have on this reapeting test");
            int numberofquestions = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
           while(numberofquestions > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" what do you want question number " + numberofquestions + " to be?");

                QuestionAndAnswer question = new QuestionAndAnswer(null,null);
                question.answer = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine(" what do you want question number " + numberofquestions + "'s answer to be?");
                question.answer = Console.ReadLine();
                numberofquestions--;
                QuestionAndAnswer.numberofquestions++;
            }


        }


         class QuestionAndAnswer{
            public string question;
            public string answer;
            public static int numberofquestions;
            public QuestionAndAnswer(string _question,string _answer)
            {
                question = _question;
                answer = _answer;


            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: wrong wrong wrong way of going about it. you don't make a unique class for every question. There's an infinite number of questions, and you'd need an infinite number of identifiers to "name" those per-qusetion objects. You create a generic "question" object, which is **ALWAYS** called 'question'. internally you can give that qusetion a unique ID (a number? whatever... it's up to you) so you can uniquely tell one question apart from another.

Comment: You probably don't want the value `numberofquestions` to be inside a class containing a single `question` and `answer`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to store a collection of `QuestionAndAnswer` separately.

When you do this within the loop.

`QuestionAndAnswer question = new QuestionAndAnswer(null,null);`

The variable is scoped to a single iteration of the loop, so once the loop repeats you loose that previous information.

Create a collection before the loop, within the loop add your `QuestionAndAnswer` objects into the `List`. The information within the `List` will then be available after the loop has completed.

```
List<QuestionAndAnswer> allQuestionAndAnswers = new List<QuestionAndAnswer>();

while(numberofquestions > 0)
{
    ...other code here
    QuestionAndAnswer question = new QuestionAndAnswer("The question", "The answer");
    allQuestionAndAnswers.Add(question);
}
```

Additionally, you are setting `question.answer` twice, I'm guessing the first one should be `question.question`.

```
QuestionAndAnswer question = new QuestionAndAnswer(null,null);
question.answer = Console.ReadLine(); //Once here
Console.WriteLine(" what do you want question number " + numberofquestions + "'s answer to be?");
question.answer = Console.ReadLine(); //And again a second time
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
List<QuestionAndAnswer> qList = new List<QuestionAndAnswer>();
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello, please enter how many questions you would like to have on this reapeting test");
    int numberofquestions = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
   for(int i=0;i<numberofquestions;i++){        
        Console.WriteLine(" what do you want question number " + i.ToString() + "'s QUESTION to be?");

        QuestionAndAnswer question = new QuestionAndAnswer(null,null);
        question.question = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(" what do you want question number " + i.ToString() + "'s ANSWER to be?");
        question.answer = Console.ReadLine();
        qList.Add(question);
        //NumberOfQuestions is now qList.Count
    }

    startFlash();
}
private static void startFlash(){
    string hell = "hot";
    Random rnd = new Random();
    while(hell!="freezing"){

    int index = rnd.Next(qList.Count);
    QuestionAnswer qA = qList[index];
    Console.WriteLine("Question "+index.ToString()+": "+qA.question);
    Console.ReadKey(true);
    Console.WriteLine(Answer: "+qA.answer+"\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: You've got 2 `{{` and 2 `}}` round the `for` loop... Is that a typo? :)

Comment: Yeah - thanks...trying to type directly into answer box screwed me up.

Comment: No worries - I suffer terribly trying to type directly in the box - Notepad++ for the win! ;)

Comment: BTW - it would be best to throw in a quick method of persistence here so you didn't have to type in the list every time. Just saving to disk using TextWriter or something. Unless the # of QA is small and you WAN to type them in every time.

Comment: @GeoffJames - you meaning OP not "YOU." Arrgh. I'm on a roll today -- downhill into a brick wall.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should rethink your approach a little to what you are trying to accomplish. Without changing your code too much you enter your questions and answers which are added to a list until you type the word finished. The questions are then prompted over and over until you type the word exit. Hope this gives you some ideas to expand on.

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Use a list to collect your QuestionAndAnswer objects
        List<QuestionAndAnswer> questions = new List<QuestionAndAnswer>();
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, please enter how many questions you would like to have on this reapeting test");
        int questionCount = 1;

        // loops until you type finished
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" what do you want question number " + questionCount + " to be?");
            QuestionAndAnswer question = new QuestionAndAnswer(null, null);
            string response = Console.ReadLine();
            if (response.ToUpper() == "FINISHED") break;
            question.question = response;
            Console.WriteLine(" what do you want question number " + questionCount + "'s answer to be?");
            question.answer = Console.ReadLine();
            //Add the question (QuestionAndAnswer) to the list
            questions.Add(question);
            question.questionNumber = questionCount;
            questionCount++;
        }

        //This section will ask the questions until you type exit
        while (true)
        {
            foreach (QuestionAndAnswer qa in questions)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Question #{0} out of {1}: {2}", qa.questionNumber, questions.Count(), qa.question));
                Console.Write("Type you answer and hit <Enter>: ");
                if(Console.ReadLine().ToUpper()=="EXIT") break;
                Console.WriteLine(qa.answer);

            }
        }

    }
}


class QuestionAndAnswer
{
    public string question;
    public string answer;
    public int questionNumber;
    public QuestionAndAnswer(string _question, string _answer)
    {
        question = _question;
        answer = _answer;

    }
}
```